# How to calculate pow() with modulo for real numbers?

Tags: python, vb.net, pow

I want to perform a power operation combined with a modulo.  I have trouble performing this `pow()` function with real numbers.

This works fine for integers:

```
pow(2,6000,400) = 176
```

However, this returns an error with real numbers:

```
pow(1.4142, 6000, 400)
```

I have tried also the `math.pow()` function but it doesn't
work either... how can I get this to work with real numbers ?

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: am using only VB and Python

Answer (score 3):

The python function `pow()` accepts 2 or 3 arguments. In your case, `pow(x,y,z)` does `x` power `y` and applies a modulo `z` to the result.  But the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) is explicit:

> If the second argument is negative, the third argument must be
>   omitted. If z is present, x and y must be of integer types, and y must
>   be non-negative.

So:

- Your first call works fine, because the arguments comply with the requirements.  Note that despite `pow(2,6000)` being a huge number,  the result of the combined modulo operation can be calculated easily without overflow, by using properties on [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) of integers.
- Your second call fails with an error, because the first argument is not an integer. The workaround would be to decompose your operation into `pow(1.4142,6000) % 400`, because [modulo](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) is defined for real numbers. 
   Unfortunately, `pow(1.4142,6000)` is too big and causes an overflow error. This is because contrary to the python integers which are of unlimited range, [real numbers are limited](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) by the range of the C floating point encoding.

P.S.: I assumed that it's about python and not VB, because [VB's `pow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) accepts only 2 arguments.

**Edit: hint for a workaround**

Here a little workaround that makes use of the fact that technically, a floating point number is not a mathematical real of unlimited precision, but a rational number.  We can then make use of the numerator and denominator and use integer operations to master the huge numbers:

```
n=pow(14142,6000)         # take the first argument multiplied by a 10 exponent to make it an integer
d=pow(10000,6000)         # keep track of this 10 exponent
i=n//d                    # integer division to compute the integral value
r=n-d*i                   # remainder of the integer division 
precision=6               # precision 
f=r*pow(10,precision)//d  # keep the 6 most significant digits 
result=(i%400)+(f/pow(10,precision))
```

The result is 271.048181 to the 6th digit.  I let you as an exercise the writing of a function that performs this in a less artisanal way.

Comment: This helps so much!!!!  Thank you!!!  :)  Will experiment with this.

Comment: Christophe, could you tell me how accurate you feel that returned value of "271.04" would be?  Would it be very precise?

Comment: According to the [rules of error propagation](http://www.fas.harvard.edu/~scphys/nsta/error_propagation.pdf) it's +/- 0.4243 so that the exact value should be btw 270.62 and 271.48